# Setting different Character Images

Tags: java, image

im creating a FlappyBird Mock, its four player so each player has a different image, i have managed to set the image for the first one but i cant seem to set them for the others.

I have a class for the bird where i set the first image and i have the main class where i created the 3 other birds, not sure where i alter the images and how i should. Help would be appreciated.

```
 public Bird(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        this.color = Color.red;
        this.radius = 30;

        this.gravity = 6;
        this.isAlive = true;
        this.score = 0;
        try {
            this.read = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Images/41.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PaintingPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

public class FlappyBird extends TimerTask implements KeyListener{
    private Bird flappyA;
    private Bird flappyB;
    private Bird flappyC;
    private Bird flappyD;
```

Comment: How do i change the image for the other characters, atm they all have the same image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well considering the path to your image is always the same in that code.

I'm not sure to understand what really is your issue but if all you want is to have a different image for each flappy you should try this :

```
public Bird(int x, int y, String imageName)
{
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;

    this.color = Color.red;
    this.radius = 30;

    this.gravity = 6;
    this.isAlive = true;
    this.score = 0;
    try {
        this.read = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Images/" + imageName + ".png"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PaintingPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Then in your main class you would instanciate flappy :

```
flappyA = new Bird(0, 0, "image0");
flappyB = new Bird(0, 0, "image1");
flappyC = new Bird(0, 0, "image2");
```

Edit : Your Images folder should be at the root of the project, "src" should only be used for code source files.

Comment: When the OP builds their application, this code will no longer work.  The `src` folder will not exist when the program is built.  Resources contained within the context of application (those included within the applications Jar for example) need to be loaded differently

Answer (score 0):

Once you application is built, the `src` directory will no longer exists and you will no longer be able to access the resources embedded within your application as you would (or are) if they existed on the file system, for example

```
this.read = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Images/41.png"));
```

Will throw a `FileNotFoundException`.

To load embedded resources, you need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream`, for example...

```
this.read = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Images/41.png")));
```

Instead of hardcoding the file name in this manner you should rely on a variable to make the process more flexible...

```
String imageToBeLoaded = ...;
//...
this.read = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(imageToBeLoaded)));
```